# How to write code in python that reads large dataset and converts to specific datatypes with good performance

Tags: python, types

My Python script reads data from an input stream. My aim is to tokenize the stream line by line. This allows me to recognize the fields in the incoming data. I then convert the fields to the required data types.

I am currently reading from `sys.stdin`. After performing some logic, I send the result to the `std.out` file.

My issue at the moment is that my code appears really slow. I profile the python script with [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) and 1 gigabyte of data took 2.5 hours. The profiler shows that a lot of time is spent in calling the conversion functions `int`, `float` and `str`. I definitely think there is a better way to write this code.

```
##IMPORT STATEMENTS
import time ,sys ,os
from datetime import datetime 
from distutils.util import strtobool 


fpy_backup_stderr=sys.stdout
sys.stdout=sys.stderr

##UTILITY VARIABLES

fpy_sep=","
fpypy_output_row_start="fpy_pyout:"
fpy_carriagereturn=":fpy_py_cr:"
fpy_linefeed=":fpy_py_lf:"
fpy_null="PY_NULL"
fpy_end_row_signal="@@"


fpy_debug_flag=False
def fpy_debug(msg):
 MSG_PREFIX=""
 msg=MSG_PREFIX+msg
 if fpy_debug_flag == True:
  sys.stderr.write(msg + "\n")


####MAP OUTPUT FIELD TO PRECISION
fpy_column_out_precision_dict ={
 "p_string_out":100
}

##COLLECT THE CURRENT VALUE OF THE OUTPUT FIELDS
def fpy_collect_out_columns_asmap():
 e_val ={
  "p_bigint_out":p_bigint_out,
  "p_double_out":p_double_out,
  "p_int_out":p_int_out,
  "p_string_out":p_string_out
 }
 return e_val

file=open("/export/home/devbld/ftpy.target.txt" + str(os.getpid()),"a+")
@profile
def fwrite ( elem):pass
 #file.write(elem)

##GENERATE THE OUTPUT ROW
def generateRow():
 column_values=fpy_collect_out_columns_asmap()
 sys.stdout=fpy_backup_stderr
 fwrite(fpypy_output_row_start)
 if constant_out is None:
  fwrite(fpy_null)
 else:
  fwrite(str(constant_out))
 fwrite(fpy_sep)
 if p_bigint_out is None:
  fwrite(fpy_null)
 else:
  fwrite(str(p_bigint_out))
 fwrite(fpy_sep)
 if p_double_out is None:
  fwrite(fpy_null)
 else:
  fwrite(repr(p_double_out))
 fwrite(fpy_sep)
 if p_int_out is None:
  fwrite(fpy_null)
 else:
  fwrite(str(p_int_out))
 fwrite(fpy_sep)
 if p_string_out is None:
  fwrite(fpy_null)
 else:
  prec=fpy_column_out_precision_dict["p_string_out"]
  astr=str(p_string_out).replace("\n",fpy_linefeed)
  fwrite(astr[:int(prec)])
 fwrite("\n")
 sys.stdout=sys.stderr

##MATERIALIZE THE INPUT ROW COLUMNS
def fpy_materialize_columns(fpy_row_arr):
 global p_bigint,p_double,p_int,p_string,constant
 index =0

 v = fpy_row_arr[0]
 if v is not None:
  p_bigint = int(v)
 v = fpy_row_arr[1]
 if v is not None:
  p_double = float(v)
 v = fpy_row_arr[2]
 if v is not None:
  p_int = int(v)
 v = fpy_row_arr[3]
 if v is not None:
  p_string =v


start= time.time()

@profile
def main_func():
 print("calling main_func")
 fpy_row_container=""

 rows=map(str.rstrip,sys.stdin.readlines())

 ##for fpypy_line in sys.stdin:
 for fpypy_line in rows:
  temps=fpypy_line.rstrip()
  if temps.endswith(fpy_end_row_signal):
   size= len(fpy_end_row_signal)
   fpypy_line= temps[:-size]
   fpy_row_raw=fpypy_line

   ##RESET THE INPUT FIELDS
   p_bigint=None
   p_double=None
   p_int=None
   p_string=None
   constant=None

   ##RESET THE OUTPUT FIELDS
   constant_out=None
   p_bigint_out=None
   p_double_out=None
   p_int_out=None
   p_string_out=None

   fpy_row_arr=fpy_row_raw.split(fpy_sep)
   for n,i in enumerate(fpy_row_arr):
    if i == fpy_null:
     fpy_row_arr[n]=None


    v = fpy_row_arr[0]
    if v is not None:
     p_bigint = int(v)
    v = fpy_row_arr[1]
    if v is not None:
     p_double = float(v)
    v = fpy_row_arr[2]
    if v is not None:
     p_int = int(v)
    v = fpy_row_arr[3]
    if v is not None:
     p_string =v

   #MAIN

   p_bigint_out=p_bigint
   p_double_out=p_double
   p_int_out=p_int
   p_string_out=p_string
   constant_out=constant
   column_values={
    "p_bigint_out":p_bigint_out,
    "p_double_out":p_double_out,
    "p_int_out":p_int_out,
    "p_string_out":p_string_out
   }
   sys.stdout=fpy_backup_stderr
   fwrite(fpypy_output_row_start)
   if constant_out is None:
    fwrite(fpy_null)
   else:
    fwrite(str(constant_out))
   fwrite(fpy_sep)
   if p_bigint_out is None:
    fwrite(fpy_null)
   else:
    fwrite(str(p_bigint_out))
   fwrite(fpy_sep)
   if p_double_out is None:
    fwrite(fpy_null)
   else:
    fwrite(repr(p_double_out))
   fwrite(fpy_sep)
   if p_int_out is None:
    fwrite(fpy_null)
   else:
    fwrite(str(p_int_out))
   fwrite(fpy_sep)
   if p_string_out is None:
    fwrite(fpy_null)
   else:
    prec=fpy_column_out_precision_dict["p_string_out"]
   astr=str(p_string_out).replace("\n",fpy_linefeed)
   fwrite(astr[:int(prec)])
   fwrite("\n")
   sys.stdout=sys.stderr

   fpy_row_container=""
  else:
   print("wait why did i miss " + fpypy_line) 
   fpy_row_container=fpy_row_container + fpypy_line

main_func()

end=time.time()
timeelapsed=(end-start)/60
sys.stderr.write("time elapsed in minutes " + str(timeelapsed))

file.close()
```

Comment: You really should run a code formatter on this. Better yet, learn to format your code in accordance with [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The results suggest to me that the bottleneck is not in your code at all. How much CPU does the script consume when you run it? If it's less than 100% on an individual core, your I/O channel is probably where time is spent, waiting for more data to arrive or for written data to be committed to disk.

Comment: Update .  I have not been able to identify the bottleneck at the currently .  I profiled the Linux machine on which the python code is executed and CPU hoovers around 55% , 77%  use . Using IOStat  , I can see that disk IO  busy time is not  high.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the profiling results (probably just the highlights, as already described in the prose) and some test data?

Comment: Update.  turns out that the slowness I observed was a I/O buffering issue after all.

Comment: I/O buffering was the issue . At this point here is where stand . Running the command  'python script.py ' from my java program on 10MB takes about 30 seconds .    However  running the commands 'python script.py > temp.data' and then 'cat temp.data'  is 5 to 6 times faster .  Can I change the sys.stdout to mimic the combination of python and cat command ? or can I pipe to a virtual file ?

Comment: Try `python -u` for a start ...?

Comment: no that does not fix it . Setting the u option actually makes the matter worse here.